# Jenkins run jobs in sequence and also specific

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 4 Jenkins jobs: `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` that should run in that order when running them all.
I used the Parameterized Trigger plugin to set the order sequence and Pipeline plugin to watch the flow but I still want to have the ability to:

```
1. Run only Job A
2. Run only jobs B and D
3. Run from job A ( according to sequence )
4. Run from job C ( according to sequence )
```

Item 1 can be run from the specific job,
Items 3 and 4 can be run from a Pipeline view (is there a better way?)
But what about item 2?

Currently I have these 4 jobs but in the future I may have more jobs which mean more combinations so I'm looking for a generic solution and avoid write code for every combination I may need.

P.S. Is there a way to have one place to run each one of the items I wrote and not having a different way to run each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) and create a *Multijob* (e.g. `Run all`) where you add your 4 other jobs in a *MultiJob Phase*. To run them sequentially you have to configure *Job execution type* to *Running phase jobs sequntially*.

You may create a MultiJob for each sequence you need adn add those jobs (`Run B and D`).

Comment: Multijob enable to run ll jobs in sequence but I will not be able for example start from job C, also I was looking for a more Generic solution since I don't want to create Multijob job for every possible combination, what if I will add jobs D & E, I will need to create many Mutijobs jobs.

Comment: Then, why is it that you have multiple combinations and don't run them all at once, everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Using pipelines I would personally do things a little bit differently : instead of having `A` `B` `C` and `D` jobs I would define these four steps as pipelines functions, e.g. :

***functions.groovy***

```
def A() {
  stage "A"
  // doAjob
}

def B() {
  stage "B"
  // doBjob
}

...
```

Then I would create a job for each of your "item" `1` `2` `3` and `4`, so your item 2 would look like this :

***jobItem2.groovy***

```
node() {
  def functions = load 'functions.groovy'
  // Now just call declared functions
  functions.B()
  functions.D()
}
```

and so on.

Of course you could declare A (that could be launched on its own) as a specific job and mix jobs and functions. With such a mix your item3 could look like this :

***jobItem3.groovy***

```
node() {
  // Call A as a job
  build 'A'

  // Call other steps as functions
  def functions = load 'functions.groovy'
  // Now just call declared functions
  functions.B()
  functions.C()
  functions.D()
}
```